# Confused about preventing duplicates with new Kafka idempotent producer API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

My app has 5+ consumers consuming off of five partitions on a kafka topic.(using kafka version 11) My consumer's each produce a message to another topic then save some state to the database, then do a manual_ immediate acknowledgement and move onto the next message.

I'm trying to solve the scenario when they emit successful to the outbound topic. then we have a failure/lose the consumer.  When another consumer takes over the partition it will emit ANOTHER message to the outbound topic. This is bad :(

I discovered that kafka now has idempotent producers but from what I read it only guarantees for a producers session.

"When producer restarts, new PID gets assigned. So the idempotency is promised only for a single producer session" - (blog) - https://hevodata.com/blog/kafka-exactly-once

This seems largely useless to me.  In my use-case the whole point is when I replay a message on another consumer it does not duplicate the outbound message.

Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: It's not totally clear where you are committing your consumer offsets here. I'd assume after you acknowledged the produced message. This puts you in a mode of read-process-write and you'd want to either use Kafka streams or implement your own transactional producer  https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/ idempotency producer isn't a fit here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll have to look into it more tomorrow.  Seems like a transaction id would be hard to implement

Comment: You should not be using the consumer to commit offsets when using transactions - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using transactions, you shouldn't use ANY consumer-based mechanism, manual or otherwise, to commit the offsets.

Instead, you use the producer to send the offsets to the transaction so the offset commit is part of the transaction.

If configured with a `KafkaTransactionManager`, or `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` the Spring listener container will send the offsets to the transaction when the listener exits normally.

If you don't use a Kafka transaction manager, you need to use the `KafkaTemplate` (or `Producer` if you are using the native APIs) to send the offsets to the transaction.

Using the consumer to commit the offset is not part of the transaction, so things will not work as expected.

When using a transaction manager, the listener container binds the `Producer` to the thread so any downstream `KafkaTemplate` operations participate in the transaction that the consumer starts. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_transactional_listener_container).

Comment: Ahh i was not aware the transaction would commit the consumer and producer acknowlegements.